# JavaScript Looping through select options

Tags: javascript, html, forms, loops, increment

I'm trying to loop through a select form to increase the value of the selected option whenever it is clicked. I've done some searching but I haven't found something I need..Here is the html

```js
var counter = 0;
function myFn(){
  var myOptionIndex = document.getElementById('selectForm').selectedIndex;
  var myOptionValue = document.getElementById('selectForm').value;
  var myOption = document.getElementById('selectForm').options;

  for (var i = 0; i < myOption[myOptionValue].value; i++) {
    counter++;
  }

  document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = myOption[myOptionIndex].text 
  + " has been selected " + counter + " times";
}
```

```html
<form action="" id="voteForm">
    <select name="select-form" id="selectForm">
        <option value="1"> Option 1</option>
        <option value="1"> Option 2</option>
    </select>
    <button type="button" id="castVote" onclick="myFn();">Cast Your 
    Vote
   </button>        
</form>
<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: Are u trying to increment the value by 1 each time it’s clicked.

Comment: Change selected option value.
`document.getElementById('selectForm').options[myOptionIndex].value = 'new value'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't actually need any counter. You can use the `myOptionValue` variable, since it's equal to the actual value of the selected option. Furthermore the `for` loop is unnecessary as well. You have already the variable `myOptionIndex`, which is equal to the index of selected `option`. Now you just need to increase the value of `myOptionValue` in the function and display this variable instead of `counter` in your `results` - `div`.
It would look like this :

```
function myFn(){
      var myOptionIndex = document.getElementById('selectForm').selectedIndex;
      var myOptionValue = document.getElementById('selectForm').options[myOptionIndex].value;
      var myOption = document.getElementById('selectForm').options;
    myOptionValue++;
    document.getElementById('selectForm').options[myOptionIndex].value++;
      document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = myOption[myOptionIndex].text 
      + " has been selected " + myOptionValue + " times";
}
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/sunny7/3sk4nrpd/) also the demonstration of this example in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

You're never changing the option's value, you're just updating the `counter` variable. That one variable doesn't have information about each option.

There's no need for a loop, just use the selected index.

And you should set the initial values of the options to `0`, since neither of them has received any votes yet.

```js
var counter = 0;
function myFn(){
  var myOption = document.getElementById('selectForm').options;
  var myOptionIndex = document.getElementById('selectForm').selectedIndex;
  var myOptionValue = myOption[myOptionIndex].value;
  myOptionValue++;
  myOption[myOptionIndex].value = myOptionValue;

  document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = myOption[myOptionIndex].text 
  + " has been selected " + myOptionValue + " times";
}
```

```html
<form action="" id="voteForm">
    <select name="select-form" id="selectForm">
        <option value="0"> Option 1</option>
        <option value="0"> Option 2</option>
    </select>
    <button type="button" id="castVote" onclick="myFn();">Cast Your 
    Vote
   </button>        
</form>
<div id="results"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for my English. To the point - the script will work only when the form is changed. That is, if the first option was selected, and again select it - the counter will not increase.

```js
let increase=()=>results.innerText=`${selectForm.options[selectForm.selectedIndex].innerText} has been selected ${selectForm.options[selectForm.selectedIndex].value++} times`;
voteForm.addEventListener('change',increase);
```

```html
<form id="voteForm" action="">
  <select id="selectForm" name="select-form">
    <option value="1"> Option 1</option>
    <option value="1"> Option 2</option>
  </select>
  <button id="castVote" type="button">
    Cast Your
    Vote
  </button>
</form>
<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: Clicking on the button doesn't increase the number of votes for the selected option. It only counts when you change the menu selection.

Comment: I realise this is just an example, but using element IDs as global variables is a really bad idea. If your intention is less code, then `selectForm.options[selectForm.selectedIndex].innerText` can be `selectForm.value` (but has the same ID/global issue).

Comment: @RobG  I just used the opportunities already available. The top-starter pointed to the id for the elements, which automatically creates global variables. Since they already were, why not use. Advise him to use classes to identify elements better.